# Is it possible to restrict access to certain URLs for individual programs?

Tags: windows-7, security, firewall, url, sandbox

I have a certain use case where I want to whitelist a list of URLs that a certain application can access. In other words, I want to sandbox it, but don't have access to blocking or white listing those specific URLs for that exe file only. Is there anyway to do it without using Global Settings (that will affect other programs)? I know I could run inside of VM, but that really seems like a waste of resources. Is there a more elegant solution? I would also like to restrict/allow URL access based off of domain name, preferably.

To reiterate, I still want to program to access certain and only certain URLs. I am using Windows 7. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say you dont have access?

Comment: Cannot connect to. So let's say theoretically I am have a massive phobia of Google (which I don't). I have this program that I love, but wants to access Google.com. The access of Google.com is not essential to the running of the programming (the exception is handled). Can I make it so it cannot access Google.com or more specifically any domain besides necessaryURL.com?

Comment: I would just modify the hosts file.  But that would disable access for any application.

Comment: @Ramhound exactly. I need a solution that sandboxes it for individual exes and alike.

Comment: The default Windows Firewall allows for configuring rules by program . . .

Comment: @ernie How? I thought you could only make exceptions. In other words, allow programs through.

Comment: To create a blacklist, create an outbound rule that blocks connections for that app, and then in scope tab, you'll need to add the IPs for the connection.  It'll be a little complicated if their DNS resolves to multiple IPs as you'll need to enter each of the IPs.

Comment: Cool. What about a whitelist? Is there a way to do that?